# Issue and Error while inserting values of an array to a stored procedure EF in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having an issue when trying to insert data to stored procedure of 5 array variables the error I am getting is the following `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`. can you see what I am doing wrong here? the variables lotlist, netweightlist, grossweightlist and serialnumberlist can have 1 to many data to be inserted to my stored procedure.

method that will create my stored procedure

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BarcodeReceivingApp.Persistence;
using BarcodeReceivingApp.Persistence.Repositories;

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp.Functionality
{
    public class StoredProcedureInsert
    {
        private readonly BarcodeReceivingFootPrintDbContext _barcodeReceivingFootPrintDbContext = new BarcodeReceivingFootPrintDbContext();

        public void CallManualBlindBarcodeParsingEventRequestFootPrintProcedure
        (
            decimal actualPackagedAmount, int actualPackagedPackId, string lotLookupCode,
            int warehouseId, int materialId, string vendorLotLookupCode, DateTime vendorLotManufactureDate, 
            DateTime vendorLotExpirationDate, int shipmentId, decimal netWeight, 
            decimal grossWeight, string serialLookupCode, string licensePlateLookupCode
        )
        {
            _barcodeReceivingFootPrintDbContext.Database
                .ExecuteSqlCommand
                ("EXEC noram_reporting.ManualBlindBarcodeParsingEventRequest " +
                 "@ActualPackagedAmount, @ActualPackagedPackId, @LotLookupCode, @WarehouseId, @MaterialId, @VendorLotLookupCode," +
                 "@VendorLotManufactureDate, @VendorLotExpirationDate, @ShipmentId, @netWeight, @grossWeight, @serialLookupCode, @licensePlateLookupCode",
      new SqlParameter("@ActualPackagedAmount", actualPackagedAmount),
                    new SqlParameter("@ActualPackagedPackId", actualPackagedPackId),
                    new SqlParameter("@LotLookupCode", lotLookupCode),
                    new SqlParameter("@WarehouseId", warehouseId),
                    new SqlParameter("@MaterialId", materialId),
                    new SqlParameter("@VendorLotLookupCode", vendorLotLookupCode),
                    new SqlParameter("@VendorLotManufactureDate", vendorLotManufactureDate),
                    new SqlParameter("@VendorLotExpirationDate", vendorLotExpirationDate),
                    new SqlParameter("@ShipmentId", shipmentId),
                    new SqlParameter("@netWeight", netWeight),
                    new SqlParameter("@grossWeight", grossWeight),
                    new SqlParameter("@serialLookupCode", serialLookupCode),
                    new SqlParameter("@licensePlateLookupCode", licensePlateLookupCode)
                    );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method that calls that method to insert data to my stored procedure

```
private void SendStoredProcedureDataToFootPrint()
        {
            var lotList = _connection.ParseLot();
            var netWeightList = _connection.ParseNetWeight();
            var grossWeightList = _connection.ParseGrossWeight();
            var serialNumberList = _connection.ParseSerialNumber();
            var material = _unitOfWork.Shipments.GetLastMaterialEntry();
            var scanCounts = _connection.CountReceivingBarcodeEntries();
            var packagingId = _unitOfWork.Materials.GetPackagingId();
            var warehouse = _unitOfWork.Warehouses.GetWarehouseIdQuery();
            var shipment = _unitOfWork.Shipments.GetLastShipmentIdEntry();
            var licensePlate = _unitOfWork.LicensePlates.GetLastCreatedLicensePlate();


            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <= _connection.GetBarcodeList().Count; i++)
                {
                    _storedProcedureInsert.CallManualBlindBarcodeParsingEventRequestFootPrintProcedure
                    (
                        scanCounts,
                        packagingId,
                        lotList[i],
                        warehouse,
                        5785,
                        lotList[i],
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now,
                        shipment,
                        Convert.ToDecimal(netWeightList[i]) / 100,
                        Convert.ToDecimal(grossWeightList[i]) / 100,
                        serialNumberList[i],
                        licensePlate
                    );
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

so the goal is to insert data to my stored procedure in the for loop without any issues from the array variables that can have 1 or more values.

I tried other sources and no help was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have exception on .NET side due to accessing invalid index of array

```
for (var i = 0; i <= _connection.GetBarcodeList().Count; i++)
```

Should it be `i < _connection.GetBarcodeList().Count;` here? Last index of element in array is `_connection.GetBarcodeList().Count - 1` so I guess you have exception somewhere here `lotList[i],`

Comment: Thanks bro, you are correct the issue was to tiny but I guess hard to see, hehe? that resolved the issue by changing to `i < _connection.GetBarcodeList().Count;` thanks again that resolved the issue. now I can insert data to my stored procedure.